# Are the electric and magnetic fields functions on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: vector-spaces, physics

Are the electric and magnetic fields functions from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ (where $\mathbb{R}^4$ is then interpreted as space-time) or do we consider them to be functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the parametrization $r(t) = x(t)i + y(t)j + z(t)k$?  Is there a difference mathematically?  And if it can be done in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and E&M is the basis of relativity, why do physicists study relativity in Minkowski space rather than $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: The electric/magnetic field at any point is a time-dependent vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so the correct description is: $\vec{E}(x,y,z,t): \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: One can acctually work with a Euclidian metric in relativity, but this requires using imaginary time as the coordinate. This is sometimes done for some calculations (see for example [Wick rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation)), but in general this does not really simplify things (and it can confuse students even more) so people don't do it unless its needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the relativistic formulation, the "electric and magnetic field functions" are merged into a single tensor field in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (with $x,y,z,t$ coordinates), called the "Faraday field" $\bf{F}$ also known as the "electromagnetic field tensor".

The four Maxwell equations, which can be thought of as time dependent equations in $x,y,z$, are then merged into two equations in $x,y,z,t$. Specifically, the electrostatic equation
$$\nabla \cdot E = 4 \pi \rho
$$
and the electrodynamic equation
$$\partial E / \partial t - \nabla \times B = - 4 \pi J
$$
(in which I have suppressed $x,y,z$) are merged into a single $\mathbb{R}^4$ electrodynamic law
$$\bf{\nabla} \cdot \bf{F} = 4 \pi \bf{J}
$$
(in which I have suppressed $x,y,z,t$).

Similarly the magnetostatic and magnetodynamic equations, which are time dependent equations in $x,y,z$, are merged into a single $x,y,z,t$ equation.

This is all laid out quite explicitly in Section 3.4 of the book "Gravitation" by Misner-Thorne-Wheeler.

The significance of $\mathbb{R}^4$ versus Minkowsi space is that the $x,y,z,t$ versions of these equations are invariant under Lorentz transformations.